# How to set theme background color in TextMate 2?

Tags: themes, textmate

I am in the Theme Editor in TextMate 2.0 trying to set the background color for a theme. I see several background properties, none of which seem to set the background color. I can set the background color behind the line numbers, and even behind the settings window, but how do I change the background color of the main text editing window?

Answer (score 10):

It is easy.
In the TextMate tool bar (top of the screen) select:
View -> Theme
That's all.

Comment: Your answer displays the different themes, the question is how to edit a certain part of a theme (set the background color for a theme).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the `background` setting in `Settings -> Settings`:

```json
settings = (
    {   settings = {
            foreground = '#F8F8F8';
            background = '#0C1021'; <= right here
            caret = '#FFFFFFA6';
            invisibles = '#FFFFFF40';
            selection = '#253B76';
            lineHighlight = '#FFFFFF0F';
        };
    },
```